# Read data from Firebase Database and display in a textview

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin with Firebase, I am just a beginner, and I found the following code on Firebase website to read data from Firebase Database and display it in a TextView on an activity using Kotlin. I think I have understood the code and I resolved all the errors except "(Post:: class.java)". 
I don't have an activity or a class called 'Post'. What is it and what code should be in it?
What I am trying to do is to read just one data from Firebase Database and display it in a TexView.

```
val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        val post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
        // ...
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        // ...
    }
}
postReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your prompt response.

I don't have a big data structure as I am just a beginner. All I have is a database and that contain just one node and a child, value.

Answer (score 0):

`Post::class.java` returns the `KClass` reference and the `KClass` has the property `java`:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html

And since `getValue()` can have a POJO class that's why you are able to use it inside `getValue()`.

So basically the `Pojo` should be a class that will contain fields that will be mapped to the database.

For example you can create the following data class:

```
data class Post(
        val postName: String = "", 
        val postDescription: String = "")
```

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks for your prompt response. I have been trying with the code you provided. As there are errors in my code I couldn't accomplish what I was trying to. Could you provide the exact codes I would need to read a data from Firebase Database and show it in a textview. I have been trying to get it done by myself with the codes available from online but I am not able to do it. You may also let me know how my database should look like.

Comment: Just create a file Post.kt and add the code in the answer to that file. Then after `getValue(Post::class.java)` you can do 
       `textView.text = post?.postName`

Comment: Do you have data in your database?

Comment: I have some sample data. But it may be confusing if I try to explain it. Hence, I shall delete everything in it and add new data as you suggest. So that you know clearly what is the structure of the database actually is.

Comment: You need to add data using `setValue() `. `Post post = Post("post1","first post")` then get an instance of firebase and use `setValue(post)`

Comment: There isn't any error shown in the code however, app crashes when I hit the button.

Comment: This what I used to save data to the Firebase  private fun saveToFdb() { val dataX=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText).text.toString() val idKey = dbRef.push().key!! val newData=ToAddToFdb(idKey,dataX) dbRef.child(idKey).setValue(newData).addOnCompleteListener{ Toast.makeText(this,"DataX saved successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() } }

Comment: This is what I used to retrieve data.     private fun viewData() {
        val dbView= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtFdbData)
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)               

                dbView.text=post?.postName

            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // Nothing is written here so far
            }
        }
        postReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }